# Custom alternative configurations for Maven life cycles

Tags: maven, pom.xml

How can I add custom alternative configurations to the default life cycles in the `pom.xml`?

So that I for example can still call `mvn package` (default behavior), but also `mvn quickPackage` which runs the default `package` life cycle, but has e.g. `skipTests` true and the XML equivalents for other command line parameters...?

All I could find was either directing me into:

- Using extra special plugins, even write my own, which I'm not allowed here.
- Apply the configuration to *everything*, or at least *always* to a certain life cycle. Removing the default behavior of e.g. `package`.

Do I have to fallback to use command line scripts (which counters the point of having a build management system)? Or is there a `pom.xml` solution?

Comment: first `package` is not a goal it is a life cycle phase...second why would you like to skip the tests ? The command line parameters of Maven `-T 2C` there is no equivalent in `pom.xml` cause you can't simply configure it there. You could for example use `mvn -DskipTests clean package` if you like?

Comment: Thanks. Fixed Goal->Life Cycle. As said: I want to stop having build scripts like `mvn -Dbla.bla.bla=true -Dthis.that.then=true -Deverything.now=true -Dfeature.set.extra=true...`. They're messy and contradict the original intention of having build systems which encapsulate and config everything in one place.

Comment: Exactly that's the point. So why not running the tests simply? So usually a `mvn clean package` is enough? If you are using a CI system you usually use a `mvn -T 4 clean package` instead ..? So I don't see an issue. You could of course put command line configuration of Maven into `.mvn/maven.config` (things like `-T 3`) but only for your local execution not on CI....See http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what the real issue is? Your local command line call or your CI system?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Maven Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#Which_areas_of_a_POM_can_be_customized_by_each_type_of_profile.3F_Why.3F) for that, e.g.:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>quick</id>
    <properties>
      <bla.bla.bla>true</bla.bla.bla>
      <this.that.then>true</this.that.then>
      <everything.now>true</everything.now>
      <feature.set.extra>true</feature.set.extra>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Activate it with:

```
mvn ... -Pquick ...
```

Comment: Nice, almost the solution. Is there some way to create a custom life cycle which runs a default life cycle, but with that profile? Your example is already great, when you always have to `mvn clean package -Pquick`, why not `mvn quickPackage`? More compact, less error prone, you don't forget something, integrates seamlessly in IDEs (!), etc.

Comment: @Jan You could place a directory (I have one called `_bin` that contains all my standalone utils and scripts.) before `MAVEN_HOME[/|\]bin` in your `PATH` and create a `mvn.[sh|cmd]` there that calls `[${|%]MAVEN_HOME[}/|%\]bin[/|\]mvn clean package -Pquick` if invoked with `mvn quickPackage`. Yes, you can [create your own lif cycle](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=maven+create+custom+lifecycle&t=h_&atb=v79-5&ia=web) but I never had the need to do this and I think it's too much of an effort to achieve the same what you can do with a simple script.